# Transaction VOV4 how to maintain table key field? (input disabled)

Tags: sap-erp

When I try to execute the transaction code `DP80` (creating a quotation from a PM order) I get an error message number `V1320` (in French, since I use the French version of SAP): it is asking for item category.

I so far have found that the solution is to define the Item Category via the transaction `VOV4`. Here's the image of the view I got by executing that transaction code. I'm supposed to enter the same value (`SEIN`) in the selected row, but I don't know how to do it because I can't type in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit a field that is a key. In this case you should select a row, copy it, modify the entry, press ENTER and the save the table.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: your suggestion was totally helpful, however it seems that i do not have the authorization to copy or modify this table.

Comment: I tried to create an entry in this view and SAP asked for a transport order. These modifications are done in development and then they are sent to QA and finally to production. Where are you doing this entry?

Comment: I work in the `SRO` which means `the Sandbox` (I'm not sure if this is the real name in English because I use the french version of SAP)

Answer (score 0):

The said error will come in case any value is set in CMIR.  As you already found out the relevant transaction VOV4, you have copy the existing data and upon saving, one transport request would be generated, provided if you have authorization to do so.  Else, ask some of your team members who have this authorization and do it.

By the way, do you maintain Customer Material Info record where this field (Usage) will come into picture